# MacOs sed replace does not work for html file

Tags: html, bash, sed, replace

I am trying to prepend a `<h4>` tag in my document with `<button class="collapse">` and also append the closing tag `</button>` after a `</h4>` tag.

My example document looks like this:

```html
<h4 id="id1">Some text.<br />
</h4>
<div class="content">
<p>Content.</p>
</div>

<h4 id="id2">Some text 2.<br />
</h4>
<div class="content">
<p>Content.</p>
</div>

<h4 id="id3">Some text 3.<br />
</h4>
<div class="content">
<p>Content.</p>
</div>

<h4 id="id4">Some text 4.<br />
</h4>
<div class="content">
<p>Content.</p>
</div>
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

```html
<button class="collapse"><h4 id="id1">Some text.<br />
</h4></button>
<div class="content">
<p>Content.</p>
</div>

<button class="collapse"><h4 id="id2">Some text 2.<br />
</h4></button>
<div class="content">
<p>Content.</p>
</div>

<button class="collapse"><h4 id="id3">Some text 3.<br />
</h4></button>
<div class="content">
<p>Content.</p>
</div>

<button class="collapse"><h4 id="id4">Some text 4.<br />
</h4></button>
<div class="content">
<p>Content.</p>
</div>
```

What I tried is this: `sed -E -i -e 's/(\<h4\w*.*)(\n)(\<\/h4\>)/\<button\ class\=\"collapse\"\>\1\2\n\3\<\/button\>/' index.html`

It does not work though, it does not change anything, similar sed with similar regex works for a markdown file, but I can not get it to work with a html file.

I also tried find and replace in Atom editor using: `(<h4\w*.*)(\n)(</h4>)` as regex and `<button class="collapse">$1$2$3</button>` as replace and that works absolutely perfectly.

What is my mistake? Is it maybe the newline? How would I achieve what I need using sed on MacOs, I am using bash.

Thank you very much, would appreciate any help

Comment: What do you think `\w*` is doing?

Comment: Be aware that without some more sed programming, sed is strictly line-oriented.

Comment: `\w` is a GNU sed extension. I doubt it will work on MacOS sed.

Comment: @glennjackman Hi, with my limited regex experience I suppose it should find any word and *.* should include any other characted until the next group "starts", I am not 100% sure tho (beginner). I also realize that sed is strictly line-oriented, therefore I tried to use newline, is that not a proper way to do that? Thanks

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Thanks, I tried for example this and it worked: `cat test.md | sed -E 's/(#### )(\w*.*)(.\ \\)/\1, \2\3, /'` so I thought, that \w should work on MacOS as well, I might be mistaken though.

Comment: You're right. However you aren't matching the space after h4.

Comment: The line in sed's pattern space will not contain a newline (unless you use sed's looping commands among others) so there's no point trying to search for a newlinw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/^<h4/<button class="collapse">&/' -e 's:</h4>:&</button>:' infile
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. I understand the second part, but could you please explain this part: `'s/^<h4/<button class="collapse">&/'` ? I do not understand how you can achieve the replacement without including the <h4 tag after the <button tag, I understang `^<h4` means beggining, but how is this not replacing <h4 with the <button tag. Is it the & character? Can not seem to find a definitive answer on the internet. Thanks again

Comment: You got it, the `&` is replaced with the regex matched - in this case, the `<h4` (sans anchor `^`); the second part also has a `&`

Comment: Search for `&` in [this doc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html)